# _NSCFConstantString CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, ios6

App is crashing with error `_NSCFConstantString CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

when trying app with this code to save image to photo album

```
int currentimage = _imageScrollView.contentOffset.y / [pictures count];
UIImage *imageToShow = [pictures objectAtIndex:currentimage];

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageToShow, self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Comment: your array seems to contain an NSString, not a UIImage. This can be caused by an over-release of an object. Is your project using ARC? If not you should.

Comment: ARC is turned on and pictures = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"image0.png", @"image1.png", nil];

Comment: Yep, the message means that a call was made for the CGImage method, using an NSString as the object.  There is no CGImage method on NSString, so likely you've somehow gotten an NSString in the wrong place.

Comment: `@"image0.png"` is an NSString.

Comment: yes i know but how can i fix this

Comment: You presumably need to perform some sort of UIImage alloc/init sequence on the string first.

Comment: Eg, `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]`, but you probably need to supply part of the path, vs just feeding in the above file names.

Comment: Eg: `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image0" ofType:@"png"]];`

Comment: if ([[pictures objectAtIndex:index] intValue] == 0){

    
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_imageView.image, self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        
        
} else if([[pictures objectAtIndex:index] intValue] == 1) {
     
  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_imageView.image, self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
 what if i try to save image like this why this ain't working

Answer (score 2):

By the information that you gave in the comments, you are using an UIImage reference ("imageToShow") that is pointing to a NSString (element from the array), and that is why when imageToShow receive the CGImage selector, crashes.

To solve this problem, you have to put UIImage references to UIImage objects in the array.

```
UIImage *image0 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:"image0FullPath.png"];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:"image1FullPath.png"];
pictures = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image0, image1, nil];
```

If the images are in the mainbundle, you can use imageNamed instead of imageWithContentsOfFile. imageNamed receive as input only the name of the file, and search for it inside the mainbundle. imageWithContentsOfFile needs the full path.

Good Luck!